# Replacing multiple occurrences of dynamic strings?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, performance

Not sure if I could explain better in the title, but ill explain here better. I am trying to create a function that will act as a simple "templater". I feed it a string with certain tags "{{name}}" and it will replace it with a certain string.

here is what i have so far:

Calling the function:

```
loadTemplate("<div>{{name}}, {{anotherString}}</div>", {
    name: "Hunter",
    anotherString: "is amazing!!!!" 
});
```

The function:

```
// Created this to make my life easier :)
function loadTemplate(template, data) {
    var tags = template.split("{{").pop().split("}}").shift();
    console.log(tags); // This only gives me the last occurrence.
}
```

How would I loop through all the occurrences of {{variable}} in my string so i can replace it with the associated data?

Similar to `Handlebars.js` (I am wanting a SUPER lightweight and fast function, not an entire plugin)

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace

Comment: @IsmailBadawi Taking a look now, thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's pretty easy to do with one regex replacement using a callback for the substitution text:

```js
function loadTemplate(template, data) {
    return template.replace(/\{\{(\w+)\}\}/g, function(match, key) {
        return data[key];
    });
}

alert(loadTemplate("<div>{{name}}, {{anotherString}}</div>", {
    name: "Hunter",
    anotherString: "is amazing!!!!" 
}));
```

The pattern is `\{\{(\w+)\}\}`, meaning `{{`, followed by a captured word, followed by `}}`. A word is any sequence of alphanumeric characters and underscores.

You can replace `\w+` with `.+?` if you want to be able to use any key value (like, with spaces for instance) which doesn't contain `}}`:

```js
function loadTemplate(template, data) {
    return template.replace(/\{\{(.+?)\}\}/g, function(match, key) {
        return data[key];
    });
}

alert(loadTemplate("<div>{{The Name}}, {{Another $tring}}</div>", {
    "The Name": "Hunter",
    "Another $tring": "is amazing!!!!" 
}));
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer as well. Between yours and Rick's, are their any speed issues with using regex? I've heard they can be slow.

Comment: Well... mine would be faster since it does one replacement. Rick's does one replacement per key in `data`, and compiles one regex per key. But you should benchmark performance if this matters to you. Also, regexes shouldn't be slow in this case since they're basically run by the JS interpreter, which can optimize exection speed by *not* creating temporary strings. I believe they'll be faster than anything you'd be able to do yourself with string manipulations from script code.

Comment: take a look at this, would this test be "accurate": https://jsfiddle.net/fy3dcmqb/

Comment: For the given input, @LucasTrzesniewski's answer is indeed *slightly* faster than mine by approx. 0.15% (in Chrome):  http://jsperf.com/elite-gamer-regexp

Comment: @RickHitchcock I awarded Lucas the answer due to performance (since i asked for a fast, simple way if possible), but you also answered my question. Thanks.

Comment: I agree that his is the better solution.

Comment: Yeah the performance is pretty similar indeed. By the way, your benchmark should have wrapped the `loadTemplate` calls in a `for` loop with like 500k iterations (and Rick's solution is faster in that one on my Chrome). jsperf is better in that regard since it does that stuff for you.

Answer (score 4):

Do a search/replace for each key in the `data` object:

```js
function loadTemplate(template, data) {
  var RE, d;
  for(d in data) {
    RE= new RegExp('{{'+d+'}}', 'g');
    template= template.replace(RE, data[d]);
  }
  console.log(template);
}

loadTemplate("<div>{{name}}, {{anotherString}}</div>", {
  name: "Hunter",
  anotherString: "is amazing!!!!" 
});
```

Comment: I knew how to replace the data, it was the "regular expression" or looping part which confused me. I'm going to thoroughly ready the documentation on it. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I like your 'split' idea, I say stick with it:

```js
window.loadTemplate = function(template, data) {
    var i = 0;
    var bool = true;
    while (bool) {
        try {
        var tags = template.split("{")[i+2].split("}")[0];
        alert(tags);
        i+=2;
        } catch (e)
        {
            bool = false;
        }
    }
}
```

```css
td {
    border: black solid 1px;
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="loadTemplate('<div>{{name}}, {{anotherString}}</div>', {name: 'Hunter', anotherString: 'is amazing!!!!' })">Load Template</button>
```